# Random variable density from joint density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If I have a two-dimensional continuous random variable $(X, Y)$ with the density:

$f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x+y, & x, y \in [0,1] \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{matrix}\right.$

Is there a way in which I can obtain Y's density?

The probability space is $[0, 1]^2$ with Borel sets and Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Do you know how to compute $\mathbb{P}(Y \le y)$ from this?

Comment: @πr8 Can I integrate this density from $-\infty$ to $y$ with fixed $x$, and then notice that for this density to be non-zero we must have $y \in [0,1]$, so I'd only integrate on this interval? Or should $y$ be fixed? To be honest, I'm quite confused

Comment: I think you're on the right track, though there's no need to fix $x$. You just integrate the density over the region $0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le y_0$ to find $\mathbb{P}(Y \le y_0)$ - does this make sense?

Comment: @πr8 Oh, now I think I've got this!

Comment: @πr8 No.  Not quite.  That will give the Cummulative Distribution Function (CDF) rather than the requested Probability Density Function (pdf).

Comment: @GrahamKemp I'm aware; I've not claimed otherwise. With that being said, a fairly consistent route to finding pdfs is to find cdfs and then differentiate them. I like this approach because at every stage, you're dealing with statements about probabilities which are relatively concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal density function for $X$ is $\displaystyle f_X(x) ~=~ \int_0^1 (x+y)\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}\operatorname d y ~=~ (x+\tfrac 12)\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}$

But what ever would the marginal density function for $Y$ be?